# Creating a matrix in Python using given positions

Tags: python

I have been trying to create a matrix based off of a list of positions

I have a list here:

```
temp = [7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
```

Edit:
    This list represents an 8x8 matrix. 
The non-zero numbers in the list represent which row the item exists in the matrix. Its position in temp represents which column the item exists in the matrix. So the first item in temp means that there is an item in the first column, 7th row of the matrix.

and I want to have a matrix that looks like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

where the nonzero digits in the list indicate the position of the 1 in the column.

```
l = []
for x in range(1, (len(temp)+1)):
    l1 = []
    count = 1
    for y in temp:
        if count == x:
            l1.append(y)
        else:
            l1.append(0)
        count += 1
    l.append(l1)
```

I have this but it's wrong and outputs the 1 in the wrong list. I have tried everything to try and fix it (somehow this code worked with a 4x4 matrix, and I'm not sure why) but nothing has worked.

Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I made an edit to the question. Please let me know if there is still any confusion.

Comment: "Desired output had the 7 in the 7th row from the bottom. I think my list was too specific and I should change temp so that it is easier to go through and create the matrix"-- but ur expected out have 7 in first colum second row

Comment: Yes. The project was a little long so I did not post the whole thing but I had it so that the row 1 started from the bottom. Although if it just makes things too complicated I am willing to flip it and have row 1 start from the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing like this, seems to be an easier way

```
def prep(index, item, my_list):
    my_list[item - 1] = item
    return my_list[::-1]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(zip(*[prep(idx, item, [0] * len(temp)) for idx, item in enumerate(temp)]))
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. This works great, however I was wondering if there was a way to have the 7 in the second list (I reworded my question again)?

Comment: @user3246701 I don't see the pattern. What does 0 between 7 and 6, signify ?

Comment: The non-zero numbers in the list represent which row the item (7) exists in the matrix. Its position in temp represents which column the item exists in the matrix. So the first item in temp means that there is an item in the first column, 7th row of the matrix.

Comment: @user3246701 But as per your expected output, 7 is in 1st row, not in the seventh row.

Comment: Desired output had the 7 in the 7th row from the bottom. I think my list was too specific and I should change temp so that it is easier to go through and create the matrix.

Comment: @user3246701 Finally I understood what you are saying I guess. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Works. Thank you for your patience! Best and fastest response

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work:

```
temp = [7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
pos=0
matrix=[]
for e in temp:
    l=[0]*len(temp)
    l[pos]=e
    matrix.append(l)
    pos=pos+1
print l
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. This works great, however I was wondering if there was a way to have the 7 in the second list (I reworded my question again)?